# 'random_password' filters not taking effect

Tags: password

The function below is intended to filter WordPress' default password generation however when either adding a user or resetting the password, it doesn't apply it. What am I missing?

```
function wpgenerapass_generate_password( $extra_special_chars = false ) {
        $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        $chars .= 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $chars .= '0123456789';
        $chars .= '!@#$%^&*()';
        
        if ( $extra_special_chars ):
            $chars .= '-_ []{}<>~`+=,.;:/?|';
        endif;
        
        $wpgenerapass_password = ''; // Initialize the password string
        $password_length       = 8;
        
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $password_length; $i += 1 ) {
            $wpgenerapass_password .= substr( $chars, wp_rand( 0, strlen( $chars ) - 1 ), 1 );
        }
        
        return apply_filters( 'random_password', $wpgenerapass_password );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, your PHP syntax is wrong. Try these,

```
function wpgenerapass_generate_password( $password, $length, $special_chars, $extra_special_chars ) {
    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $chars .= 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $chars .= '0123456789';
    $chars .= '!@#$%^&*()';
    
    if ( $extra_special_chars ) {
        $chars .= '-_ []{}<>~`+=,.;:/?|';
    }
    
    $wpgenerapass_password = ''; // Initialize the password string
    $password_length       = 8;
    
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $password_length; $i += 1 ) {
        $wpgenerapass_password .= substr( $chars, wp_rand( 0, strlen( $chars ) - 1 ), 1 );
    }
    
    return $wpgenerapass_password;
}

add_filter( 'random_password', 'wpgenerapass_generate_password', 99, 4 );
```

Comment: This seems to invalidate the key when using `retrieve_password_message`  and `wp_new_user_notification_email`

Comment: What do you want to do with these functions?

Comment: These are used to send custom messages to the users when either creating new users or resetting password for existing users.